# Converting a long CFG to Chomsky Normal Form

Tags: context-free-grammar

I know there's a lot of examples on here, although I just cant seem to get this one, it seems significantly harder than any examples I've seen, the grammar is:

> S-> ABAC | BaA
>
> A-> Aa | BAbC | lambda
>
> B-> bB | aBaC | lambda
>
> C-> a|b

now by removing the lambda's, and replacing a's and b's with Ta, Tb I have:

> S-> ABAC | BAC | BC | ABC | BTa| AAC | Ta
>
> A-> ATa | Ta | BAbC | BTbC | AbC | TbC
>
> B-> TbB | TaBTaC | Tb | TaTaC
>
> C-> Ta | Tb
>
> Ta-> a
>
> Tb-> b

Now my question is, where do I go from here, do I just replace every single RHS variable with a different letter until I have massive list?

Comment: To add, i just don't know when i should stop...